# How can I request an image from the user, output it and get the src of this image?

Tags: javascript, image, request, src

I need to request image from the user, then display it on the screen. I also need to get the src of this image for later work. (get the src to be processed by the program)

I only managed to request an image and display it on the screen. But I need to get the src of the image to be processed by the program (src="")

Comment: You can convert the image data to a blob, then use [`URL.createObjectURL()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL_static)

Comment: How did you display it on the screen without setting the `src`?